# Fix prestashop error. When sorting while having faceted search active, some products disappear

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In my site https://alto.7180.eu/it/12-regali i'm having a problem with sorting products.
When i sort by price, some products disappear, it seems like the query just doesn't obtain them.

This happens only when the faceted search module is active and i order by price. The other sortings work just fine. When i disable the faceted search module, the sort by price works fine.

I'm using prestashop 1.7 and faceted search 3.2.1. I also tried the latest version of the module, but still it doesn't work.

In general, i did some changes to html and css, but i didn't edit any php file. I'm sure the problem is not about my customization because i've seen similar questions asked in other forums, obviously i haven't found the answer.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not here to fix problems with 3rd-party modules, let alone for fixing _anything_ without seeing relevant code. You should really rather contact the provider of that module for support.

Comment: I wanted to know if anybody had already come up with a solution, but thanks anyway

Comment: Almost a year but the problem is still unsolved here too https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/20298

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to rebuild all indexes and all prices in the `ps_facetedsearch` module.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the problem appears in categories where "Set Color Donna Corto" product is. Try to disable it and check the filter. If it helps then try to modify all product's information and rebuild all indexes